# Firebase OAuth won't redirect on phone

Tags: oauth, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

Once I get directed to Facebook, Google, or Twitter for authentication and provide my credentials, then at the point I get redirected, all it displays is a white screen. I want to say that it's not redirecting me back to my application.

Btw, this happens when I run my Ionic app on my Galaxy S5 phone. The redirect works fine when I run it on Chrome in my laptop.

This is my code.

```
ref.authWithOAuthPopup(provider, function(error, authData) {
            if(authData){
                $timeout(function(){
                    $location.path('tab/profile');
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Error',
                    template: 'Try logging in again.'
                });
                console.log(error);
            }
    });
```

Comment: What happens if you use [authWithOAuthRedirect](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithoauthredirect.html) instead of authWithOAuthPopup?

Comment: @Kato I have tried that and the exact same thing happens. It stay hung on a white screen.

Comment: There's still not much here to go on. Certainly can't reproduce. Do you have version info? Can you upgrade to the latest (and still provide your version info)?

Comment: I solved the issue. The solution was installing the org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser plugin by running the following command: cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to install the following plugin: org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.

You can run the following command:

`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser`