# Steroids.js + Firebase Twitter Authentication Hangs on White Screen

Tags: javascript, twitter, firebase, angularfire, steroids

I have a Steroids app running on iOS, and have been having trouble successfully  authenticating with Firebase.

My authentication function looks like this, per the [Firebase API guide to authenticating with Twitter.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/twitter.html)

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/");
var sync = $firebase(ref);
$scope.loginWithTwitter = function() {
  ref.authWithOAuthPopup("twitter", authHandler);
};

function authHandler(error, authData) {
  if(error) {
    supersonic.logger.log("Login failed!" + error);
  } else {
    supersonic.logger.log("Authenticated successfully with payload: " + authData);
  }
}
```

The above code when activated popups a window in the app, which after signing in says that it is redirecting back to the app. Then...

Here is a screenshot of the screen I'm stuck on:
http://wcet2.waketech.edu/sirhodes/ios.png
Clicking "Done" in the bottom left corner, outputs this to console:

Screenshot of return (I tried twice, hence the double message):
http://wcet2.waketech.edu/sirhodes/console.png

---

Important notes:

- I am using AngularFire, not the plain javascript API for most of the app, excluding the authentication method.
- I did check "Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter" box in the Twitter App settings
- I have set the consumer key and secret provided by, refreshed these values, and updated them in Firebase Forge.
- Versions:

  - Angular : 1.3.14
  - Steroids: 3.5.10
  - Firebase: 2.2.1
  - AngularFire: 0.9.2
  - iPhone 5s iOS: 8.2
- [Link to similar redirect issue, but using the Ionic Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130046/firebase-oauth-wont-redirect-on-phone)

Comment: Does Steroids support `window.open(...)`? Is there an equivalent to Cordova's `InAppBrowser`?

Comment: @RobDiMarco steroids claims to package the InAppBrowser plugin in their default build process. Should I try `window.open(...)` inside a `<script>` tag in one of my pages?

Comment: Yeah, give it a shot and see if it actually works! Also note that Firebase Authentication will only invoke the InAppBrowser module if it detects `window.phonegap` or `window.cordova` in the context of the page.

Comment: @RobDiMarco thanks for the tip, the `window.open(...)` did work. Still not sure at this moment what the issue is...